# HTML5 cross-browser PNG sequence for 3D

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm in the middle of creating a 3D video slot machine game in HTML5.

The game is great and it works perfectly in Firefox. It uses PNG sequences to give a 3D look to the characters within the game and the effects. The total amount of PNG's is 550 (70 per animation).

The main problem comes with Safari (Desktop, iPad and iPhone). When I load in the longer animations, which are over 100 PNG's, the framerate drops dramatically to around 4. I assume this is because of the Safari image memory not being able to hold 550 images well - despite it only totaling about 10mb.

Given that file size is also critical, as it's a web game, I considered swapping all the PNG's to GIF's in order to roughly half the size - However, before I embark on this journey, I figured the same thing would happen because of the number of images.

So the question here is - For a PNG sequence style game, what would be the best cross-browser compatible way of doing this in HTML5?

My only thought so far is to have a spritesheet per animation, placed into a div and moved on the left/top. Alternatively, could it be an issue with the way im preloading the images?

Unfortunately I'm unable to show any source code.

Comment: A good idea would be to animate only things that actually move. That is to say, instead of rendering 70 full-frame PNGs, use a fixed background and make tiny sprites move on it. This, of course, if the whole image is not changing.

Comment: http://www.hosted101.net/slots/display/Katun.html This is the Flash version of the game, to give you an idea of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Im on a phone so i can't look up the code and post it as an answer.  But at work a collegue did something similar, but I think its more a optical trick. Have a look here, just enter some stupid phone no in the form http://www.logosonnerie.com/Ope/jeu.aspx

Comment: That's the general idea, except with a whole lot more animations going on. When you get chance, if you could check the above link you'll understand more. Thanks for the link though

Comment: Im not sure if thats what my colleague did but me I would use css sprites (look em up) All images on one long vertical png and as an animated background, instead of many individual images.

Comment: you said something about gifs instead of pngs, and that you would have the same amount of images. But what if you use animated gifs?

Comment: gifs (8bit 256colors) won't save you file size,  if it does then you are optimizing your pngs incorrectly. Its unfair to compare 8bit gif to 24bit pngs .. use 8bit pngs and pngout

Comment: changing the file format will change the load time, not the memory used. It depends on the way you work, but can you envision using svg ? or even javascript draw function using path (some software have plugins for translation). Because svg's are much smaller. Consider also doing some effects (like shining) with javascript (expl : lighter composite mode + clipping can do miracles) to reduce the number of image you need to use.